# Spring Security CustomUserDetails not authenticating

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring security in my spring boot app.
My app works well with in-memory authentication.
But when users are loaded from the database it does not authenticate. It returns 403 access denied error code. UserDetailsService is able to fetch the user information from the database but I dont know where it is going wrong. I am new to spring.

here is my complete code related to security

**User.java**

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME")
    private String displayName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Set<Role> userRoles;

    private String profilePicturePath;

}
```

**Role.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Data
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String role;

}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.people.users.pojos.User;

@Repository("userRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**RoleRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.people.users.pojos.Role;

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {

}
```

**UserService.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.people.users.pojos.User;
import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.people.users.repositories.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRep;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {

    List<User> users = userRep.findAll();
    return users;
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userRep.save(user);
    }

    public void updateUser(User user) {
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userRep.save(user);
    }

    public void deleteUser(Long id) {

    userRep.delete(id);
    }

    public User getUser(Long id) {

    return userRep.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

**RoleService.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.people.users.pojos.Role;
import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.people.users.repositories.RoleRepository;

@Service
public class RoleService {

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository userRoleRep;

    public void addUserRole(Role role) {
    userRoleRep.save(role);
    }

    public void updateUserRole(Role role) {
    userRoleRep.save(role);
    }

    public void deleteUserRole(Long id) {
    userRoleRep.delete(id);
    }

    public Role getUserRole(Long id) {
    return userRoleRep.findOne(id);
    }

    public List<Role> getAllUserRoles() {
    return userRoleRep.findAll();
    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetails.java**

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(final User user) {
    this.user = user;
    }

    public CustomUserDetails() {
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    final Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    Set<Role> roles = null;

    if (user != null) {
        roles = user.getUserRoles();
    }
    if (roles != null) {
        for (Role role : roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
        }
    }
    return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {

    return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {

    return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {

    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {

    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {

    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {

    return true;
    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.people.users.pojos.CustomUserDetails;
import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.people.users.pojos.Role;
import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.people.users.pojos.User;
import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.people.users.repositories.UserRepository;

@Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    } else {

        System.out.println("______________________________________________________________");

        System.out.println("username: " + user.getUsername());
        System.out.println("password: " + user.getPassword());
        System.out.println("Roles: ");

        for (Role role : user.getUserRoles()) {
        System.out.println(role.getRole());
        }
        System.out.println("______________________________________________________________");

        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.cloudsofts.cloudschool.security.CustomUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    try {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        System.out.println("_________________________________________________");

        String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        System.out.println("_________________________________________________");
        System.out.println("You have logged in as " + username);
        System.out.println("_________________________________________________");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("_________________________________________________");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("_________________________________________________");

    }

    }

    @Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /*
     * @Autowired public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
     * throws Exception {
     * auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("student").password("student").roles(
     * "student").and().withUser("admin") .password("admin").roles("admin"); }
     */

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();
    // http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

    // http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/student/**").hasAnyRole("student", "admin");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("admin");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/library/**").hasAnyRole("librarian", "admin");
    http.httpBasic();

    // http.formLogin().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll();

    }

}
```

**Screenshots**

[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hQli.png)

[Browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjsaU.png)

[Users in the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kqx9.png)

[Roles in the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG6OI.png)

[User-Role mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy8wN.png)

[Console output after giving the credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4l2Z.png)

Answer (score -1):

You seems to using the BCryptPasswordEncoder to encrypt and decrypt password. But 'Users' table screenshot shows the password in plain text. Can you validate the place where you are saving or updating the user, it is actually encoding the password and also the password encoder bean is of type 'BCryptPasswordEncoder'

Comment: Sorry. that is the old screenshot. I actually store the encrypted password the in db. I have updated the image. please have a look at it now

Answer (score -1):

I got the problem solved.

I had to add **ROLE_** as a prefix to the roles.

Now everything works fine